# Overlay transparent png on web app camera

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am creating a web app using the mobile devices camera. Specifically a ipad mini.

I'm using the code:

So the full screen pop up with a camera, but I want to overlay a transparent image on top of the camera. So for example a sun in the top right hand corner so when the photo is taken the sun also appears in the camera.

Can anyone help me out how to add a overlay.

Thanks so much.

Comment: can you maybe add some code?
You say "I'm using the code:" but nothing more..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this:

```
#IdOfImage{
    background: url('YourImageHere')
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

All the other classes / id's have to be a lower z-index to make this image pop up over all the other ones.